# Kerberized NFSv4 share (deleted) after token expiry

Tags: kerberos, nfs, nfs4

I set up a NFSv4 server with Kerberos authentication and it runs well. However, some users stay logged in for long times such that they have to renew their tickets after some days. If during the time with an expired ticket a NFS share is accessed, e.g. by daemons, it becomes inaccessible even after the ticket has been renewed. The share is marked `(deleted)` in `df -PTh`.

In general it requires `umount /nfs/share;mount /nfs/share` to get it back on again. `-o remount` fails in most cases.

Although the general behaviour makes some sense, could anyone tell me what exactly is happening, e.g. I have no idea what the `(deleted)` status actually means?

And for practical purposes: is there any way to avoid the share to go `(deleted)` at first? After all it's just a *bad* user - no reason to block all others as well.

The client is current Debian Wheezy nfs-common 1:1.2.6-4 on a 3.2.63 kernel. Server is a Synology NAS with kernel 3.2.40 (DSM 4.3).

Thanks for your help.